# If else is not workin in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Here my Jquery code:

```
<script>
            $('.smenu li').hover(function() {       
                var lid = $(this).find('li').attr('id'); 
                closeAll(); 
               //show perticular div
                if(lid == "d1")
                    {
                        $('.hbg div#info1').show();
                    }
                else if(lid == "d2")
                    {
                        $('div#info2').show();
                    }
                else if(lid == "d3")
                    {
                        $('div#info3').show();
                    }
            });   

            function closeAll()   
            {   
                $('div#info1').hide();
                $('div#info2').hide();
                $('div#info3').hide();

            } 
          </script>
```

Here my info `div`-s:

```
<div class="hbg">
            <div class="solu_info" id="info1">
              //display information
             </div>
            <div class="solu_info" id="info2">
              //display information
             </div>
.....
</div>  

<div class="smenu">
                <ul>
                  <li id="d1"><a href="#"><img src="images/menu_hosp.jpg" border="0"></a></li>
....
```

**onmouse over the div tags are not getting changed. Why?**

Comment: This is just a piece of code, not a question ...

Comment: Post your HTML. It might be that your selector is not correct.

Comment: @all It it obvious but for u guys I have updated my question.

Comment: This is the wrong HTML snippet. Where are the `<li>` s and `.smenu` ? And no, **it is not at all obvious** and *is not working* is not an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the hover event handler, `this` is going to be an `li`, since it is attached to `$('.smenu li')`. Then `$(this).find('li')` will find `li` elements *inside* `.smenu li`, which presumably don't exist.

Answer (score 8):

if else statement is just javascript, nothing to do with jquery. It always works. If it does not what you expect it to do something in your code logic is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

<del>Maybe</del> it has to be:

```
var lid = $(this).attr('id');
```

just `alert(lid)` and  check if it contains a value (most likely not in your code).

---

You current code gets the `id` of a `li` element inside the `li` element.

---

Obviously , `if-else` will work if your code is right. Remember, it is more likely that you did something wrong as that the language has an error ;)

---

Seriously, you should read some tutorials and the documentation before posting a lot of questions here. Then you would know what `find()` is doing and which elements `$('.smenu li')` is selecting.

**Update:**

Ok, just for you:

This is your HTML

```
<div class="smenu">
    <ul>
      <li id="d1">...</li>   // #1
      <li id="d2">...</li>   // #1
    </ul>
```

the selector `$('.smenu')` will select all the `<li>`elements that I marked with `#1`.

Not when you applying `.find('li')` to such an element, it tries to find a `li` element inside the `li` element, i.e. it would select the elements I marked with `#2` here:

```
<div class="smenu">
    <ul>
      <li id="d1">  // #1
          <ul>
            <li id="foo">...</li>  // #2
          </ul>
      <li id="d2">...</li>   // #1
    </ul>
```

But this is not your structure. You don't have nested lists. You want the IDs from the `#1` elements and therefore it has to be

```
var lid = $(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: ya `alert(lid)` is popping-up `undefined`. Why it is not getting the `id` attr?

Comment: @nectar: It is all described in my answer.

Comment: I know what does it(`find`) do.the same syntax is working fine with some other jquery code.there also I am using `find()`;

Comment: @nectar: See my updated answer. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `switch` is what you need here.